# Get process memory consumption

Tags: linux, memory, ubuntu-10.10

I need a command that can get the memory consumption of a process called "job_runner_o".

Running ubuntu 10.10

Any thoughts?

Comment: Do you mean `top`?

Comment: `htop` is better, in my opinion. But I don't know if Ran wants an interactive or scriptable command.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could use `ps` column selection:

```
ps -eo vsz,rss,comm|grep job_runner_0
```

will list the virtual memory size (vsz) and resident set size (rss). The the `ps` man page for details about these columns and the other ones available.

You should also look at the files in `/proc/$pid/`, especially `/proc/$pid/status`. They contain a lot of information. For example, try:

```
cat /proc/`pgrep job_runner_0`/status
```

(This assumes that there is only one process named job_runner_0.)

Yet another quick option is `pmap`, which will list detailed process mapping information.

```
pmap -x $(pidof job_runner_0)
```

for a full detailed listing (this is present in one of the /proc files also).

If there are several processes with that name, and you just want the total mem used, this can work:

```
pmap $(pgrep job_runner_0) | grep "^ total"
```

Answer (score 5):

Execute the following on a shell:

```
grep VmRSS /proc/$(pidof job_runner_o)/status
```